# how to fetch multiple columns from join table Django model Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my model code

```
class questions(models.Model):
q_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
q_active = models.IntegerField
q_createdby = models.CharField(max_length=100)
q_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.q_name

class choice(models.Model):
c_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
c_question = models.ForeignKey(questions, related_name='choice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.c_name
```

my serializer is

```
class choiceserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
c_question = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True,
                                      slug_field='q_name')

class Meta:
    model = choice
    fields = ('id','c_name','c_question')
```

this is my view

```
class chl(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    clist = choice.objects.all()
    data = choiceserializer(clist, many = True).data
    return Response(data)
```

my output for the serializer is

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "c_name": "name",
    "c_question": "what is your name?"
},
```

I want to fetch few more columns with the serializer. I want to fetch  `q_active`, `q_created` column with it. is there any serializer relation I can use with?

I need this final json response

```
{
    "id": 
    "c_name": 
    "c_question": 
    "q_active":
    "q_created ":
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class questions(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = questions
        fields = '__all__'

class choiceserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = questions()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = (''id','c_name', 'question')
```

Comment: {
        "id": 
        "c_question": 
        "c_name":
    }, i am getting only this 3 fields